# Seemingly missing a notification. Is this a bug?

Tags: bug

The following is one of my questions on PSE:

[Additions to menagerie were strange but appreciated](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122591/additions-to-menagerie-were-strange-but-appreciated)

Yesterday user Alaiko posted a comment to this question.
Also yesterday user caPNCApn edited his previous answer to this question.

I received a notification about the comment but not the edit. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. Edits to answers never generate notifications on the SE network as standard. If you wish to receive notifications each time a particular answer is edited, you will need to actively choose to 'Follow' the answer by clicking this option beneath it:

[image: Example of where to find the Follow option]

Once you are following a post, the 'Follow' option will say 'Following' instead. To stop following a post, simply click that option again.

Comment: Thanks!  I never knew that.

Comment: This has burned me before too - it means you have to monitor those partial answers for updates... You can think of it as: You will receive notifications about changes and updates to your *own* posts (edits, comments, and answers to your questions) but a comment on or an edit to someone else's answer (even though it is an answer to your question) will give *them* the notification instead.